# Foreign Key inheritance and Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate

I hope this title isn't misleading. But I really don't know with which words to describe the problem.

So, I have three tables. Contract, Subcontract and Project.
One Contract has many Subcontracts. One Subcontract has many Projects. So each table would get a foreign key of the next "higher" table. So far so good.

Now, if the Contract is not divided into Subcontracts, it can have many Projects directly. So the Projects foreign key points either to a Subcontract - or directly to a Contract.

What is a good way to model this? And, if differing, what is a good way to model this without loosing to much of hibernates automation benefits?

Answer (score 0):

Make subcontract a subclass of contract. Contract uses project. Create a mapping reflecting your model as shown in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

I have made good experiences with the one-table approach. Particularly useful when reasoning over contracts and subcontracts at the same time.